# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Solr with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, solr

I am new to solr. I am try to get record from table using rest call using solr spring data tool. But when I am try to request url from browser then I am get the following error.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

My code is like as:

User Object:

```
public class User {

    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String fName;

    @Field
    private String lName;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
}
```

UserDao:

```
public interface UserDao extends SolrCrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AjaxResponse loadAll() throws IOException {

        List<User> users = (List<User>) userDao.findAll();
        return new AjaxResponse("Success", false, users);
    }
}
```

Aplication.properties file:

```
server.port=9111

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/solrDatabase?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.data.solr.host=http://localhost:8983/solr/
spring.data.solr.repositories.enabled=true
```

When I am try to request this url:
http://localhost:9111/app/api/users
Then I am getting exception. Can any one help me.

Comment: Does http://localhost:8983/solr/ work in your browser?

Comment: No, http://localhost:8983/solr/ is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` exception is thrown because your Spring application is unable to connect to your Solr server. Since the URL you've provided, `http://localhost:8983/solr/` does not work when you're opening it in the browser either, Solr is probably not running (as long as you're trying to connect from the same host as the code is running on, which from your other example URL seems to be true).

Make sure that Solr is actually running and able to answer requests before making any changes to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following properties into `application.properties`:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```